# Perform A - B (A\B) with Time in java?

Tags: java, time, jodatime, duration

If I have this code:

```
DateTime start = new DateTime().withTime(4, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime end = start.withTime(5, 0, 0, 0);

DateTime s2 = start.withTime(4,30,0,0);
DateTime e2 = start.withTime(5,30,0,0);

Duration d1 = new Duration(start,end);
Duration d2 = new Duration(s2,e2);

Duration result = d1.minus(d2);
System.out.println((int)result.getStandardMinutes());
```

Is there a way that I can get essentially A - B or A \ B (set theory notation)?
In this scenario the result would be 30 because the first duration has 30 minutes of time which do not occur in the second duration.

I'm not looking for a solution specifically in Jodatime, just using that to explain the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A `Duration` represents an **amount of time** (such as *"10 minutes and 30 seconds"*), but it's not attached to a timeline: 10 minutes and 30 seconds relative to what? To nothing in particular, it's just the amount of time (the values), by itself.

Specifically in Joda-Time, after creating the `Duration`, the object itself doesn't store the reference dates used to calculate it, so the `Duration` instance can't know if it's before or after a specific date (because it's an amount of time not attached to any particular date, so you can't compare it with a date).

If you want to consider a specific date (that's after or before another), and use this date to calculate the duration, you must check the date **before** calculating the duration:

```
// ignore dates before the start
DateTime date1 = s2.isBefore(start) ? start : s2;

// ignore dates after the end
DateTime date2 = e2.isAfter(end) ? end : e2;

Duration d2 = new Duration(date1, date2);
```

Or, you can do what you're already doing, but in the end, you check if `s2` or `e2` are outside the start/end interval, and add the respective durations back to the result:

```
if (s2.isBefore(start)) {
    result = result.plus(new Duration(s2, start));
}
if (e2.isAfter(end)) {
    result = result.plus(new Duration(end, e2));
}
```

Not sure if set theory really applies here, but I might be wrong (I'm not a pro in maths).